# j2me go to next midlet

Tags: java-me, midp, lcdui

I got 2 midlets A and B. How to go to midlet B when button in midlet A is click?

I need that to show sign up screen at user signup.

```
  public void commandAction(Command cmd, Item item) {
        System.out.println(cmd.getCommandType());
        if (cmd.getCommandType() == 2)
        {}
        else
        { SignupMidlet signupScreen = new SignupMidlet();
        Display.getDisplay(signupScreen).setCurrent(signupScreen);
        }
    }
```

My midlet B constructor:

```
public class SignupMidlet extends MIDlet {

    public SignupMidlet(MainMidlet mc) {
        Form a=new Form("a");
        Display.getDisplay(mc).setCurrent(a);

    }
```

Comment: why do you want to do that? (hint: most real life applications don't need that)

Comment: Bcos user signup show sign up screen

Comment: @user903772 one doesn't really need a second midlet for stuff like that; see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11181351/839601) "...from the code you posted, it looks like you are confusing extending the MIDlet class with implementing the Displayable interface. One MIDlet can switch from one Displayable to another..."

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is [JSR 211](http://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=211).
It is not available on all J2ME phones but the part of it that is usually implemented first is the one that allows switching from one MIDlet to another.

However, from the code you posted, it looks like you are confusing extending the MIDlet class with implementing the Displayable interface.

One MIDlet can switch from one Displayable to another.

If you want to share code so that one MIDlet can access code that was written for another, you should split the code into a separate jar and, unfortunately, include the jar in both MIDlets at compile time.